# Where are the XSDs that JBoss AS 7.x validates its configuration XML against?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

In order to try something out,  I want to change the urn:jboss:domain:1.3 schema.

I have located and edited jboss-as-config_1_3.xsd in /docs/schema, however it seems that this is not actually being referenced. To be sure I have also tried malforming this schema, and this has no effect.

Where is the XSD that JBoss is validating against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged this and worked out that my parsing error wasn't because the XML was being validated against a schema. It is because code in *org.jboss.as.domain.management.parsing* is looking for expected tags, and throws when unexpected ones are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it under docs/schema directory of your server. This is the location where they are stored.

Comment: isn't this the same thing OP said in the question?